# wxWidgets app hanging when using modal dialog

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have a simple wxWidgets application where I create a `wxMessageDialog` and then show it.

For some reason when I return from the startup method the app will then hang.

Here is the code:

```
bool App::OnInit()
{
    wxMessageDialog* dialog = new wxMessageDialog(NULL, "Message", wxMessageBoxCaptionStr, wxOK | wxCENTER | wxDIALOG_NO_PARENT);
    dialog->ShowModal();

    return true;
}
```

I have tried calling `EndModal()` on the `dialog` but that makes no difference.
I did see a question referencing this situation in Python but using `wxDIALOG_NO_PARENT` has made no difference to the behaviour

Any ideas what could the problem be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the application main window in `App::OnInit()` and you don't do that. If you don't create the main window, you must return `false`, not `true`.

The main window is usually a class derived from `wxFrame`. You can also use `SetTopWindow()` to let wxWidgets know what the main window is.

```cpp
bool App::OnInit()
{
  if (someErrorCondition)
  {
    ::wxMessageBox("Oh no!");
    return false; // Return false if an error occurs and you cannot create the main window.
  }
  else
  {
    wxFrame* frame = new wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, "Amazing App");
    ::wxGetApp().SetTopWindow(frame); // Optionally set the main window.
    frame->Show(); // Optionally show our main window.
    return true; // Return true if all is well.
  }
}
```

Comment: Calling `SetTopWindow(dialog)` does not resolve the issue, the reason why I need this functionality is so I can present an error message before initialising my main window

Comment: Yes, but you do not initialize a main window in the code you posted. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

The application doesn't hang, it just runs waiting until someone tells it to exit. Usually it's done by the framework itself when the last window is closed, but as you don't have any windows (the dialog is closed before `OnInit()` returns and so doesn't count), this doesn't happen. I.e. this is working as expected, what exactly would you want to happen instead?

Also note that you have a memory leak in your code. Modal dialogs are one exception to the general rule of wxWidgets destroying all the objects you give to it and are not destroyed by the framework. This is because typically you don't need to destroy them at all because they're created on the stack and not on the heap:

```
    wxMessageDialog dialog(NULL, "Message", wxMessageBoxCaptionStr, wxOK | wxCENTER | wxDIALOG_NO_PARENT);
    dialog.ShowModal();
```